# SSIS - Cannot Convert between Unicode and Non Unicode String Data Type Only in SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm getting a "Cannot Convert between Unicode and Non Unicode String Data Type" error when my package runs through SQL Agent but when I run the package through the editor I do not get an error.

The source data is in Oracle and it's being inserted into a SQL database.  None of the other packages that pull data from Oracle seem to have an issue when running from SQL Agent.

Any thoughts?

Comment: And what conclusion do you pull out of the last passage of your post?

Comment: @tombom no clue, it works when running from the local machine but not from sql agent. Other packages work in SQL agent. How can it work in one but not the other when others are successful in both?

Comment: Your last paragraph tells you, that the error is not caused by pulling data from Oracle. Must be in your package. So just compare the datatypes of your source and your destination. Google if there are differences between the datatypes of the two DB vendors and cast/convert appropriately.

Comment: @tombom - The data types were all matching.  If they were different why would it work locally but not in SQL Agent?

Comment: Check if the configuration file from where you select your datasources is different on SQL Agent.

Comment: Configuration file is the same.  That only has the database connection string and is determined via Windows Environment Variable.

Comment: Have this same exact issue with it workin on my dev box but when I run it as a job it fails everytime with the same error. Please msg me if youhave figured this out.